# How ActionEvent work and how its object is created down to do carry out the task when a button is pressed?

Tags: java, swing, awt

Can any one make me understand the flow of this logic, When button b1 is pressed then some action takes place(some statements executed), but Why we have given the syntax like below ,`ActionEvent` object `ae` is created and how it is working? 
If I don't use Inner class then Do i have any other representation for this?

```
JButton b1=new JButton();
b1.addActionListener((ActionEvent ae) -> {
    //Statements;
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by `Do i have any other representation for this?` ?

Comment: You need to read on Lambda expression and anonymous classes on the web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All ActionListeners implement the function:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
    ...//code that reacts to the action... 
}
```

This code creates a new anonymous class which implements ActionListener and overwrites the actionPerformed function to whatever you desire. A new object with this function is added to foo's internal list of ActionListeners:

```
foo.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
    @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ...//code that reacts to the action...
    }
});
```

A shorthand for this is to use a lambda expression, as the ActionListener only has one function to overwrite, so the compiler knows which one you mean (see documentation on lambdas for more information):

```
foo.addActionListener( 
    (e) -> { 
        ...\code that reacts to the action...
    } 
);
```

When an action occurs, foo will work its way through the ActionListener objects it has listed, and call actionPerformed() on each one. The code for each object's version of the function is run in turn.

Incidentally it's good practice not too do too much work in actionPerformed(), as it is executed in the Swing thread and slow performance here would mean an unresponsive user interface. If you need to run a time-consuming action in response to an action, consider starting a new thread within this function or simply setting a flag to be detected by an existing thread.

Comment: Very nicely explained, got your point, Thanks for such words . . . :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add action events like this.

```
JButton b1 = new JButton();
b1.addActionListener(this);
```

then you have to make this class

```
public void actionPerfomed(ActionEvent ae){
   if(ae.getSource()==b1){
      //your commands here
     }
}
```

Note: Make sure to implent `ActionListener`.